# Getting an error with loading css when following webpack's official guide

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, webpack-5

I'm following the 'Getting started' guide on [Webpack's webpage](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#setup) and I'm getting an error when running the build process via `npx webpack`. As this is a very small example folder I'm including here the different code snippets:

Project structure:

```
-/dist
--index.html
-/node_modules
--...
-/src
--index.js
--style.css
-package.json
-webpack.config.js
```

./dist/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Getting Started</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

./src/index.js

```js
import _ from "lodash";
import './style.css';

function component() {
    const element = document.createElement('div');

    element.innerHTML = _.join(["Hello", "webpack"], ' ');
    element.classList.add('hello')

    return element
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

./src/style.css

```css
.hello {
  color: red;
}
```

package.json

```json
{
 ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20"
  },
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");

module.export = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
};
```

when running `npx webpack` - as instructed in the tutorial, and expected to build the output of the project - I'm getting the following error instead:

```
ERROR in ./src/style.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .hello {
|   color: red;
| }
 @ ./src/index.js 2:0-21
```

As far as I understand, the css code is fine, and the project is set up correctly.

Am I missing something or should I report this as a bug to Webpack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright nevermind, I found what I was doing wrong. By typing fast I confused `module.exports` with `module.export`. I'm considering this question as closed as it was a clear and obvious fail from my side.